# Primes Equidistribute in Ray Class Groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ideal-class-group

Fix $K$ a number field and a modulus $\mathfrak m.$ Theory around the class number formula tells us that primes $\mathfrak p$ of $K$ equidistribute over all ideal classes in the normal class group, $J_K^1/P_K^{1,1}.$ (Here we use Dirichlet density.) Is it in general true that primes equidistribute over ideal classes in $J_K^{\mathfrak m}/P_K^{\mathfrak m,1}$?

Additionally, is there a corresponding "ray class number formula"? I am aware of the typical ray class number formula in terms of the class number (say, [Milne V.1.7](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf)) but am interested if there's a residue of some $\zeta$-function around here.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some thinking, I realized the answer is "yes" for somewhat unsatisfying reasons. Simply apply Chebotarev to the needed ray class field to get the result.